# AWS Gateway load balancer via K8s service

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-web-services, continuous-deployment, load-balance, sre

Is there any way to deploy the AWS Gateway Load Balancer via Kubernetes service with the annotations? I can't find any annotations to create the AWS Gateway load balancer in the documentation.

Something like using the annotations below in K8s service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-app-lb-service
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: "gateway"
spec:
  selector:
    app: my-app
  ports:
  - name: http
    protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  type: LoadBalancer
```

The same I've done for NLB & ALB with [annotations](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.2/guide/service/annotations/)